# Calculating returns from data frame does not wok

Tags: r

I have an excel file which has been read correctly in R. All packages installed
It contains: date column with label date/Disney stock price with label Disney
I need to calculate the daily returns of the stock price

This is my code

```r
##### Calculate returns #####
for(i in c(2:nrow(df))){
  df$Return[i] <- (df$disney[i]-df$disney[i-1])/df$disney[i-1]*100
}
```

but I get an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Return", value = c(NA, 4.70578659318846 : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 431
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code using `dput(df)`?

Comment: > dput(head(iris, 10))
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 
3.4, 2.9, 3.1), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 
1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: This data does not contain information on date/Disney stock prices..

Comment: Issue has been solved. Thanks for the help though! Much appreciated. You guys are heros here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first create empty column:

```
df$return <- NA
```

Comment: @user19135634 No worries! don't forget to tick on answer useful.